# Disabling a Sonassi extension causes Magento admin panel not to load and errors out

Tags: extensions, debugging

Magento CE 1.8.0.0

Working on a new client's site and I've been assigned the task of disabling and removing Sonassi WordPress Deluxe extension. I proceed to edit app/etc/modules/Sonassi_WordpressDeluxe.xml by changing active from true to false, then I clear cache. The frontend of the site continues to operate normally but when I attempt to access the admin URL, Magento renders the homepage with a new message showing in a Mage_Core_Block_Messages block that says:

```
Magento has detected a fatal error (get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given)
```

None of my var/ logs or PHP logs show any reference to this and the full page from header to footer loads. To me this implies that they have copied some of the extension code into the theme directories but I'm not sure. What is the most effective way to proceed with debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Poor WordpressDeluxe, what did it do to deserve removal* :(

Your issue is that Magento is still bootstrapping Wordpress, and thus the error you see actually stems from Wordpress itself - not Magento.

You'll find a (critical) edit in `index.php` in Magento itself where it includes the autoloader for the module. It is this that bootstraps the WP environment within Magento itself.

Just comment out/remove this line - and the module will effectively be disabled. To remove the remainder just ...

```
rm -rf app/etc/modules/Sonassi_WordpressDeluxe.xml \
       app/code/community/Sonassi/WordpressDeluxe \
       app/design/*/*/*/layout/wordpressdeluxe.xml \
       app/design/*/*/*/template/wordpressdeluxe \
       skin/*/*/*/css/wordpressdeluxe.css \
       blog
```

*Replace `blog` with the Wordpress installation directory*

Comment: Indeed, that was the fix. Thanks Ben! And it didn't do anything to me personally. We just decided to do a manual integration of WordPress to allow for a bit more customization.

Comment: That's odd. WPD is as basic as it gets - the whole point was to be a "Developers Extension" rather than a finished product. So that you could go to town making customisations to functionality whilst having a tiny module linking the two apps. In terms of display/control - its infinitely flexible, its the best possible base for a "manual/custom" integration.

Comment: And I appreciate that. We just felt that an extension was unnecessary for our specific implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely caused by a Sonassi layout XML. Check through your theme `layout` directory and look for any Sonassi related layout XML and remove them too.